# jquery code doesn't work when upgrading to jQuery v1.12.0

Tags: jquery, version, adjustment

How to change the code to fit jquery version
my jquery version was v1.4.2.
When i upgraded didnt work no more.
need help to fix it.
found the migrate.js but dodnt want to use it.
this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var mrTables = $(".mrQuestionTable");
/* var mrTables = $("table.mrQuestionTable"); in DC 7.0 is not a table */

mrTables.each(function () {
    var tbl = $(this);
    var tblTds = tbl.find("td");
    var isGrid = false;
    if (tblTds.eq(1).attr("class") != null ) {
        isGrid = tblTds.length > 1 &&  tblTds.eq(1).attr("class").indexOf("Grid") >= 0 ;
    }
    var tblInps = tbl.find('INPUT[type="checkbox"].mrMultiple');
    tblInps.each(function () {
        var inp = $(this);
        this.group = isGrid ?    /* group of checkboxes */
            inp.closest('tr').get(0) /* when is grid, group is closest row */
            : tbl.get(0);   /* else table */
        this.isNotMulti = inp.attr("name").indexOf("nmult") >= 0;
        inp.change(clearAnswers);   
    }
  );
});
```

});

and this is  clearAnswers function:

```
function clearAnswers(e) {
var el = e.target;
if (!el.checked)
    return;
var inps = $(el.group).find('INPUT[type="checkbox"][group].mrMultiple');
    // when is grid uncheck only in the same row

inps.each(function () {
    //  if checked element is notMulti unckeck all else  uncheck all notMutli 
    if (this != el && (el.isNotMulti || this.isNotMulti))
        this.checked = false;
});
```

}

Actually, the migrate.js didnt work either

Comment: Any error in console???

Comment: no. no error in console

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: yes.
here using jquery v1.4.2 you can't check the radio button together with the checkboxes
https://jsfiddle.net/Yossi1961/7td5not9/1/
here using jquery v1.12.1 you can check the radio button together with the checkboxes
https://jsfiddle.net/Yossi1961/zgojog6y/1/

Comment: Further more, it doesnt work in any jquery version higher than v1.4.2. intrigging!!

Comment: Anyone? Still need help with this one...